# How to use sibling Stack projects?

Tags: haskell-stack

I've got a project structured thusly:

```
- proj/
  - subproj1/
    - stack.yaml
    - subproj1.cabal
    - ...
  - subproj2/
    - stack.yaml
    - pkg1/
      - ...
    - pkg2/
      - ...
    - ...
```

And my *subproj1/stack.yaml* file contains this:

```
packages:
- .
- location: ../subproj2
  subdirs:
  - pkg1
  - pkg2
  extra-dep: true
```

I'm noticing inconsistent build behavior, when running "stack build" from within the *subproj1/* directory. And I'm wondering if I have set up my project structure in an inherently unstable way. Would it, for instance, be more stable to use a single *stack.yaml* file, located in the *proj/* directory?

Comment: Related? https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2545

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately there are some known issues with this setup - https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3130 .  Hopefully will be fixed at some point!  One way to work around this is to set your STACK_YAML environment variable, so that stack invocations will ignore current directory.

Comment: Thanks, @mgsloan! Can you explain why I would want stack to ignore the current directory?

Comment: @dbanas This way, it'll always use a single stack.yaml file for building a particular local package, and so things will be consistent